# Using minimum and maximum heights with Flexbox

Tags: javascript, css, flexbox

Right now I have a flex column with two items in it, and I'm trying to figure out how to get the behavior I'm looking for. In particular, I'm trying to enforce that items within have certain minimum and maximum heights.

- The first item `item1` is on top. It should grow to encompass as much vertical space as it needs, but should not shrink below 50% under any circumstance; if the contents are larger than this, it should scroll vertically.
- The second item `item2` is in the middle. It is no larger than its contents, but should not grow beyond 50% under any circumstance; if the contents are larger than this, it should scroll vertically.
- In the scenario where `item1` would stretch beyond 50%, but `item2` does not, `item2` should not shrink so that it is smaller than its contents. `item1` should develop a vertical scrollbar instead.
- In the scenario where both `item1` and `item2` are bursting at the seams with content (too much to fit in the available space), they should both take up 50% of the available space. This is to say, the growth of `item2` takes precedence over the growth of `item1`.
- The entire column should always stay within a fixed height.

(I promise I'm not trying to be demanding, I'm just trying to be really super specific!)

Here's the SCSS code I currently have:

```
.column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;

  .item1 {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    overflow-y: scroll;
  }

  .item2 {
    flex: 0 1 auto;
    overflow-y: scroll;
  }
}
```

This gets me most of the way there, but in the case where both items grow out of control, `item2` ends up growing to overtake `item1`. Also, in the case where only `item1` becomes overlarge, `item2` shrinks down, which I'd rather not have.

But to summarize, and really answer the most pressing part of this question, **can I use maximum heights and minimum heights in combination with Flexbox, and how?** Simply adding `min-height` and `max-height` appears to have no effect.

EDIT: someone asked for a working example. This should work, though it might make you go blind.

https://jsfiddle.net/TheSoundDefense/oxykdhpt/1/

EDIT 2: the code now has `item1` and `item2` in isolation, making `item3` irrelevant, so I removed it.

Comment: Please provide a working example

Comment: yes..can use both

Comment: I can not understand the part *The first item item1 is on top. It should grow to encompass as much vertical space as it needs, but should not shrink below 50% under any circumstance; if the contents are larger than this, it should scroll vertically*

Comment: @vals sorry, that is confusingly worded. The minimum size for it is 50%, but it can grow as much as it needs to so long as it does not force `item2` to shrink. Meanwhile, `item2` can grow up to 50%. If the contents of either `item1` or `item2` are larger than the space it is currently allowed, it should scroll vertically.

Comment: Much clear now ! I will try to find a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's see if this what you want.

I have removed the flex basis from item2 , and adjusted somehow the styles

```css
.column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 500px;
}
.column .item1 {
  background-color: red;
  flex: 1 0 50%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.column .item2 {
  background-color: blue;
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  max-height: 50%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
textarea {
  resize: vertical;
}
```

```html
<div class="column">
  <div class="item1">
    <textarea></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="item2">
    <textarea></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This it behaves exactly how I want in the JSFiddle. There are still some issues getting it to work in the app, but that's because of a messy layout that needs to be reworked. Thanks!

Comment: Happy that it helped you !